# magento2 js change dropdown select option

Tags: magento2

I have write in form.phtml of Magento_Contact. when I choose the option in the first dropdown if there is information, the second dropdown will be displayed

```
<div class="field dropdown required">
        <label class="label" for="dropdown"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Dropdown') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Dropdown') ?>" value="" class="options-dropdown" type="options" data-validate="{required:true}">
                <option value=""><?= __('--Please choose an option--') ?></option>
                <?php 
                    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
                        $rsStr = $this->helper('Mageplaza\ContactOptions\Helper\Data')->getConfig('contactoptions/contactoptions/first_dropdown_'.$i);
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo 'secend_dropdown_'.$i ?>"><?php echo $rsStr ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <select name="dropdown2" id="dropdown2" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Dropdown') ?>" value="" class="options-dropdown-2 no-display" type="options" data-validate="{required:true}">
                <option value="" class="no-display"><?= __('--Please choose an option--') ?></option>
                <?php 
                    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
                        $rsStr2 = $this->helper('Mageplaza\ContactOptions\Helper\Data')->getConfig('contactoptions/contactoptions/secend_dropdown_'.$i);
                        $attr1 = explode(",",$rsStr2);
                ?>
                    <?php for($j = 0;$j<count($attr1);$j++){ ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $attr1[$j] ?>" class="<?= 'secend_dropdown_'.$i ?> no-display"><?php echo $attr1[$j] ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'mage/translate'
    ],
    function ($, modal, $t) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('select[name="dropdown"]').change(function () {
                var opChoose = $(this).val();
                $(this).parent().find('.options-dropdown-2').toggleClass('no-display');
                $(this).parent().find('.'+opChoose).toggleClass('no-display');
                //$(this).parent().siblings().find('.options-dropdown-2').addClass('no-display');
                $(this).parent().siblings().find('.'+opChoose).addClass('no-display');
            });
        });
    })
```

But when the first i choose it working and continue it be hind

[image][image][image]

[image]

Comment: please explain more.

Comment: Please describe you problem in detail so we can try so find solution.

Comment: Yes, when I choose the option in the first dropdown if there is information, the second dropdown will be displayed. i have added 1 image source

Comment: please update you question and  elaborate more.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **You need to set your select values be like this**

```
<select id="city" name="city">
  <option value="0">Select City</option>
  <option value="1">Manchester</option>
  <option value="2">Leicester</option>
  <option value="3">Londra</option>
</select>

<select id="street" name="street">
  <option value="0">Select Street</option>
  <option value="1">Street 1</option>
  <option value="1">Street 2</option>
  <option value="1">Street 3</option>
  <option value="2">Street 4</option>
  <option value="2">Street 5</option>
  <option value="2">Street 6</option>
  <option value="1200">Street 7</option>
  <option value="1200">Street 8</option>
  <option value="1200">Street 9</option>
</select>

$('#city').change(function() {
    $('#street option').hide();
    $('#street option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').show();
    // add this code to select 1'st of streets automaticaly 
    // when city changed
    if ($('#street option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').length) {
      $('#street option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').first().prop('selected', true);
    }
    // in case if there's no corresponding street: 
    // reset select element
    else {
      $('#street').val('');
    };
});
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40436512)

Comment: Hi. thank you it working. can you help me if drop2 is not there then can the slect option be hidden

Comment: i have add image number 4 the options not have text

Comment: Because the first load the dropdown 2 be hide

Comment: on  page load  add this $("selector").hide()

Comment: I don't understand what you mean yet, can you help me with the code?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53640850 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38628096

Comment: Hi Msquare, if i use this way at my email i use {{var data.city}} it will get value = 1. How way can i get the value is Manchester? Can you help me?

Comment: Please share your updated code into your question.